# Url Rewrite Pass Test But Not Redirecting

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I installed a URL Rewrite Module 2 in my iis and i have this rule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ASPX to ASP Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="([_0-9a-z-\.]+).com/([_0-9a-z-]+).aspx$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:1}.com/{R:2}.asp" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Basically what i wanted was to create match things like www.test.com/default.aspx and redirect it to an it's asp version so when i type www.test.com/default.aspx it will redirect to www.test.com/default.asp.

Not sure what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain name is not part of the URL that is matched against your regular expression. Does it really matter what the domain name is?  I would say, as long as the URL ends with `.aspx` it should redirect to the same page ending in `.asp`. That is very easy to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ASPX to ASP Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}.asp" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```